# How I can retrieve all user activity from linkedin

Tags: api, linkedin-api, social-media, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying to get user details like all posts and shares or user activities from linkedin, when I am trying get this method https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List({encoded personUrn}) I am always getting below message I am using linkedin V2 API

```
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access:     GET-authors /ugcPosts","status":403}
```

same thing happens for: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{personUrn}

**LinkedIn Documentation Here:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#retrieve-ugc-posts-by-authors

Comment: Do you have the w_member_social permission

Comment: Yes I have w_member_social_permission